# Getting errors while installing mysql-python for flask

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pip, mysql-python

I am using python v3.7. I want to install mysql-python for flask application. I got `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'`, and searched on internet where I found that this can be solved by installing either **mysql-python** or **mysqlclient**.
But, when I tried to install **mysql-python** using command `pip install mysql-python` and got following errors. Please help to resolve them. Thank you.

```
    Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting mysql-python
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: mysql-python
  Building wheel for mysql-python (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for mysql-python (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Anshu\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hx2vj4vu\\mysql-python\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Anshu\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hx2vj4vu\\mysql-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Anshu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-rqv0mwcp'
       cwd: C:\Users\Anshu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hx2vj4vu\mysql-python\
  Complete output (29 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7
  copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  running build_ext
  building '_mysql' extension
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" "-Ic:\program files (x86)\python37-32\include" "-Ic:\program files (x86)\python37-32\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
  _mysql.c
  c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\include\pyconfig.h(203): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysql-python
  Running setup.py clean for mysql-python
Failed to build mysql-python
Installing collected packages: mysql-python
    Running setup.py install for mysql-python: started
    Running setup.py install for mysql-python: finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Anshu\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hx2vj4vu\\mysql-python\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Anshu\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hx2vj4vu\\mysql-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Anshu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-q9lznfeo\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Anshu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Include\mysql-python'
         cwd: C:\Users\Anshu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hx2vj4vu\mysql-python\
    Complete output (29 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" "-Ic:\program files (x86)\python37-32\include" "-Ic:\program files (x86)\python37-32\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
    _mysql.c
    c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\include\pyconfig.h(203): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'basetsd.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Anshu\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hx2vj4vu\\mysql-python\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Anshu\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hx2vj4vu\\mysql-python\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Anshu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-q9lznfeo\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Anshu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Include\mysql-python' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes people face same error with visual C++ tools, launch setup again and also select windows 8.1 / 10 SDK depending upon your OS. This will fix basestd.h error.

If it is still not working, try launching build tools from: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools.

Another alternative would be, just install anaconda 2 or 3 (64 bit if also you don't want memory errors). It contains all the important packages prebuilt: sklearn, matplotlib, scipy, numpy, pandas and even web development frameworks such as flask.

i hope this helps <3